# passing vector to function c++

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing

I have a main.cpp test.h and test.cpp> I am trying to pass my vector through so i can use it in test.cpp but i keep getting errors.

```
   //file: main.cpp
    int main(){
        vector <Item *> s;
         //loading my file and assign s[i]->name and s[i]-address
         tester(s);
    }

    //file: test.h
    #ifndef TEST_H
    #define TEST_H
    struct Item{
        string name;
        string address;
    };
    #endif

    //file: test.cpp
    int tester(Item *s[]){
        for (i=0; i<s.sizeof();i++){
            cout<< s[i]->name<<"  "<< s[i]->address<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }



    ---------------errors--------
    In file included from main.cpp:13:
    test.h:5: error: âstringâ does not name a type
    test.h:6: error: âstringâ does not name a type
    main.cpp: In function âint main()â:
    main.cpp:28: error: cannot convert âstd::vector<Item*, std::allocator<Item*> >â to âItem**â for argument â1â to âint tester(Item**)â
```

Comment: the std::vector type is not an array, it just acts like an array.  You have to change Item *s[] to std::vector<Item *>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `std::vector<T>` and `T* []` are not compatible types.

Change your `tester()` function signature as follows:

```
//file: test.cpp
int tester(const std::vector<Item>& s)   // take a const-reference to the std::vector
                                         // since you don't need to change the values 
                                         // in this function
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i){
        cout<< s[i]->name<<"  "<< s[i]->address<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are several ways you could pass this `std::vector<T>` and all have slightly different meanings:

```
// This would create a COPY of the vector
// that would be local to this function's scope
void tester(std::vector<Item*>); 

// This would use a reference to the vector
// this reference could be modified in the
// tester function
// This does NOT involve a second copy of the vector
void tester(std::vector<Item*>&);

// This would use a const-reference to the vector
// this reference could NOT be modified in the
// tester function
// This does NOT involve a second copy of the vector
void tester(const std::vector<Item*>&);

// This would use a pointer to the vector
// This does NOT involve a second copy of the vector
// caveat:  use of raw pointers can be dangerous and 
// should be avoided for non-trivial cases if possible
void tester(std::vector<Item*>*);
```

Comment: i have different functions. one im going to change the "const vector". im just trying to pass it so i can stop getting so many errors

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as `std::vector<Item *> &` (reference to vector) and use iterator to iterate through it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should `#include <string>`.
2. `string name` should read `std::string name` etc. Same goes for `std::vector`.
3. You're calling `tester()` with a `vector`, yet it expects an array (the two are not interchangeable).
4. `s.sizeof()` is incorrect for both an array and a vector; for the latter, use `s.size()` or, better yet, use an iterator.

These are just the errors that immediately jump out; there may be more.

Answer (score 1):

A `vector` is not an array.

```
int tester(vector<Item *> &s)
```

(pass as a reference to avoid copying or if you need to modify)

You also need to modify your code inside the `tester` function to work correctly as a vector.

Comment: do i need to change this in my test.h and test.cpp?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix

```
test.h:5: error: âstringâ does not name a type
```

first, probably by `using namespace std;` and `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing includes

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

and you need to use `std::string` and `std::vector<>`. A `std::vector` is not an array, so you should pass the vector as reference

```
int tester(std::vector<Item*> & vec) { //... }
```

or even as `const std::vector<Item*> &` if you are not going to modify the passed vector.

Also, are you sure, that you'll need a vector of pointers? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well i have code that is going to edit s[i]-> name and s[i]-address in another function in my code that is not posted. With &vec do i need to post that in test.h and in test.cpp?