# Using a pointer to a std::vector to access elements in C++

Tags: c++, function, vector, stl

I want to pass to a function a std::vector but i wont want to copy the whole vector. I just want to pass the adress to the vector. So i try to use a pointer and i find out that i cant use the brackets to acces which element from the vector i want. How do i do that? This come gives me the error "
`cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'`"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void f(vector<int>* x);

int main()
{
    vector<int>a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);
    f(&a);
    return 0;
}

void f(vector<int>* x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x->size();i++)
        cout<<x[i];
}
```

Comment: *I want to pass to a function a std::vector but i wont want to copy the whole vector* then you want to use a reference, not a pointer.  It makes this problem go away.

Comment: You can use `x->at(i)`. But using a reference is better, as @NathanOliver says.

Comment: Or "cout<< (*x)[i]"

Comment: x is a pointer to a `vector<int>`. Therefore, `x[i]` gives you a `vector<int>`, and not just a plain `int`. You can't use a pointer to access something in exactly the same way as if it were the object itself. That's what a pointer means, after all. It's not the same object. It's a pointer to the object.

Comment: I get a completely different error.

Comment: Pass it as const reference, as in the code. Passing by reference is the same as using a pointer, except language syntax prevents from passing a null pointer to the function.

void f(const vector<int>& x);

int main()
{
 vector<int>a;
 a.push_back(1);
 a.push_back(2);
 a.push_back(3);
 a.push_back(4);
 a.push_back(5);
 f(a);
 return 0;
}

void f(const vector<int>& x) 
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i< x.size(); i++)
  cout << x[i] << '\n';
}

Comment: See my answer here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677007/passing-vector-to-function-c/7677043#7677043

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
cout << x[i];
```

to this:

```
cout << (*x)[i];
```

or even better this:

```
cout << x->at(i);
```

since `x` is a *pointer* to the vector.

But didn't you know already? I mean you used `x->size()`, and not `x.size()`...

However, why are you passing a pointer to the function? A reference would be fine, and would allow the body of your function as it stands in your question to work fine. And since you are just printing, a const reference, would be nice, like this:

```
void f(const vector<int>& x)
{
   // same body as in your question
}
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but your compiler should generate a warning for your for loop, of this kind:

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}' [-Wsign-compare]
     for(i=0;i<x->size();i++)
             ~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Fix it by declaring `i` as an `unsigned int`, or `size_t`.

Comment: `at` and `operator[]` aren't exactly equivalent. For `std::vector` the `at` method does bounds checking. The distinction is more significant for other containers such as `std::map` where `at` and `operator[]` are not always interchangeable. One is `const` and the other default constructs values when they aren't found.

Comment: Indeed @FrançoisAndrieux, thanks for the comment. Do you suggest I modify somehow my answer? If yes, how?

Comment: `x->at(i);` is a fine suggestion for clarity. But since the first two examples are identical in behavior, using `x->operator[](i);` would be more consistent with the other examples. Now, rather clarify or consistency is more important is up to you. I personally don't think any change is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `const` reference in this case, instead of raw pointer:

```
void f(const vector<int> &x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x.size();i++)
        cout<<x[i];
}
```

and call it without taking address:

```
f(a);
```

This would also eliminate another problem in your code, you should check passed pointer to `f()` for `nullptr` before dereferencing it.